# Problems to check a Checkbox in a PDF using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to check a checkbox in a particular PDF File (https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/f1042s--2015.pdf) for the CopyE (last page) using `iText`. The checkbox label is `AMENDED` and `PRO-RATA BASIS REPORTING`. This variable seems to be mutually exclusive, I can't check both of them at the same time (Different from the other pages CopyA, CopyB, CopyC and CopyD).

Using the tool `iText RUPS` (http://developers.itextpdf.com/tutorial/itext-rups-use-rups-change-your-pdf-syntax-and-dictionaries) I was able to identify the fields. So I have:

`c1_1_0_[0]` and `c1_1_0_[1]` for the `CopyE` different from others that are `c1_1[0]` and `c_1_2[0]`. In other words, the `checkboxes` from the `CopyE` share the same `name` while the rest don't.

The question is: Is there a way to `disable` the Mutually Exclusive and check both at the same time? Thank you.

Edit:

In the meanwhile I solved.

I need to add this line:

`form.removeXfa();`

Comment: ISO 32000 is clear: 1 name = 1 field = 1 value.

Comment: Hey man, sorry, I solved already. I just needed to add `form.removeXfa();` and was solved.